# Proof of a "obvious" set equivalence.

Tags: real-analysis

My book states that, when $f: E \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$,

$$ \{ x \mid f(x) \le a \}= \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\{ x \mid f(x) < a + \frac{1}{k} \right\}$$

$$\{ x \mid f(x) < a \} =\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\{ x \mid f(x) \le a - \frac{1}{k} \right\}$$

Alright, I think I get confused as to when to use a $<$ symbol and when  we should use $\le$.

I don't really understand why $\le$ gives us $\{ x \mid f(x) < a \}$ but $ <$ gives us $ \{ x \mid f(x) \le a \}$

Please explain, i've been confused about this for some time and can't prove it to myself.

Comment: The big difference is actually $+\frac{1}{k}$ and $-\frac{1}{k}$ and $\bigcap$ versus $\bigcup$. The first is true if you replace $<$ with $\leq$ on the right hand side, and the same is true replacing $\leq$ with $<$ on the right side of the second formula.

Comment: And what is meant by $\overline{\mathbb R}$? Is it $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$, the extended real line?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The main way to prove two sets, $A$ and $B$, are equal is to prove $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.

In both of the above cases, one inclusion is trivial.

For the other direction, you'll need to apply the Archimedean property of the real numbers. Specifically, if $\epsilon>0$ then there is a positive integer $k$ so that $\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \{x : f(x) \leq a\}$, then it is immediate that $f(x) < a+ \frac{1}{k}$ for every possible $k$. On the other hand if $x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty\{x: f(x) < a + \frac{1}{k}\}$, then $f(x) < a + \frac{1}{k}$ for every possible $k$. This implies that $f(x) \leq a$ by taking the supremum over all $k \in \mathbb N$, and this is the source of your confusion. Taking the supremum doesn't preserve the strict inequality. The other set equality can be proven similarly.

Consider this: If $f(x) < 0 + \frac{1}{k}$ for every possible $k$, does this mean that $f(x)< 0$?  No, because $f(x)$ could be equal to $0$ since $0 < 0 + \frac{1}{k}$ for every $k$.